# Retrofit service works only once

Tags: retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using retrofit to login to my API, but if, for example, I insert a wrong password and try to login again, the service is not called again.

It seems that the second call gets "stuck" in the repository, never reaches the service.

This is my first android app and i'm struggling with this situation.
Tks in advance for any help you can provide on this.

This is the code for my app.

DI

```
class Fiscalizacao : Application(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidModule(this@Fiscalizacao))


        bind() from singleton {
            Autenticacao(
                instance()
            )
        }

        bind<IAutenticacaoDataSource>() with singleton {
            AutenticacaoDataSourceImpl(
                instance()
            )
        }

        bind<IAuthenticationRepository>() with singleton {
            AuthenticationRepositoryImpl(
                instance()
            )
        }


        bind() from provider { AutenticacaoViewModelFactory(instance(), instance()) }

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this)
    }
}
```

Service

```
interface Autenticacao {

    @POST("auth")
    fun authAsync(@Body user: RequestBody): Deferred<AutenticacaoResponseResource>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(connectivityInterceptor: IConnectivityInterceptor): Autenticacao {
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build()

            return Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("http://10.110.100.216/identity/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(Autenticacao::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

DataSource

```
class AutenticacaoDataSourceImpl(
    private val autenticacao: Autenticacao
) :
    IAutenticacaoDataSource {
    private val _authResponse = MutableLiveData<AutenticacaoResponseResource>()
    override val authResponse: LiveData<AutenticacaoResponseResource>
        get() = _authResponse

    override suspend fun auth(user: CredentialsResource?): LiveData<AutenticacaoResponseResource> {
        try {
            val userJsonObject = JsonObject()
            userJsonObject.addProperty(Parameters.USERNAME.value, user?.utilizador)
            userJsonObject.addProperty(Parameters.PASSWORD.value, user?.password)

            val result = autenticacao
                .authAsync(
                    userJsonObject.toString()
                        .toRequestBody(contentType = "application/json; charset=utf8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                )
                .await()

            _authResponse.postValue(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(e.cause.toString(), e.message, e)
        }

        return authResponse
    }
}
```

Repository

```
class AuthenticationRepositoryImpl(
    private val autenticacaoDataSource: IAutenticacaoDataSource
) : IAuthenticationRepository {

    override suspend fun auth(user: CredentialsResource?): LiveData<AutenticacaoResponseResource> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@withContext autenticacaoDataSource.auth(user)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class AutenticacaoViewModel(
    private val authenticationRepository: IAuthenticationRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    lateinit var user:CredentialsResource

    val login by lazyDeferred {
        authenticationRepository.auth(user)
    }
}
```

View Model Factory

```
class AutenticacaoViewModelFactory(private val authenticationRepository: IAuthenticationRepository, ) :
    ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return AutenticacaoViewModel(authenticationRepository) as T
    }
}
```

Coroutines

```
fun <T> lazyDeferred(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Lazy<Deferred<T>>{
    return  lazy {
        GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
            block.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class AutenticacaoFragment : ScopedFragment(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by closestKodein()

    private val authViewModelFactory: AutenticacaoViewModelFactory by instance()
    private lateinit var viewModel: AutenticacaoViewModel

    val gson = Gson()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding: AutenticacaoFragmentBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.autenticacao_fragment, container, false)
        binding.model =
            AppGlobalObject
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, authViewModelFactory)
            .get(AutenticacaoViewModel::class.java)

        mAutenticacao.setOnClickListener(listenerService)
    }

    private val listenerService =
        View.OnClickListener {
            when (it.id) {
                R.id.mAutenticacao -> {
                    login(this.requireContext())
                }
            }
        }

       private fun login(context: Context) = launch {
        viewModel.user = gson.fromJson(
            gson.toJson(AppGlobalObject.autenticacao.user),
            CredentialsResource::class.java
        )

        val result = viewModel.login.await()

                result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
                    if (response == null) return@Observer

                    val login = Utilities().validateStatusCodeOK(response.error)
                    when {
                        login -> {
                            Utilities().setLoginStatus(login, context)
                        }
                        else -> {
                            mPassword.error = "Erro no Login"
                        }
                    }
                })
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code it doesn't look like it's your first app!!

Comment: I have 15 years of .NET development experience. I didn't say it was my first development project. But thank you very much for your help solving my problem...